# Using return one in factorial in c

Tags: c, function

```
#include<stdio.h>

long int factorial(int n);

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Factorial of %d = %ld", n, factorial(n));
    return 0;
}

long int multiplyNumbers(int n) {
    if (n>=1)
        return n*factorial(n-1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Why are we using return one in second function? I thought that return one means error. Is it true?

Comment: A recursive function needs an exit condition otherwise it would go forever through 0, -1, -2, etc.

Comment: As a side note: Do not call this function multiply numbers. It should be called factorial.

Comment: And another side note: it is convention that `0! = 1` so the if statement should be slightly modified so well.

Answer (score 1):

Here in this program they tried to find the factorial of a given number.
return 1 is used because  if we give '0' as input, then the condition        if (n>=1) fails then immediately returns 1 as output because 0! is "one".